# Spark read file into a dataframe

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I get a corrupt record when I try to read the below file in.

I am trying to use `SqlContext.read.Json(file location)` but get `_corrupt_record:string`. Could someone help me out? Added the head of the dataset below for the file that i am trying to read in.

Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

For reading multiline json, you need to pass an option `multiLine = True`:

```
df = spark.read.json('/path/to/json', multiLine=True)
```

And you should consider using the Spark Session to read json, instead of using the deprecated SQL context.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who wants to do it in scala, you can do it as below :

```
val df = spark.read.option("multiline",true)json("/path/to/json")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val DB_DETAILS_FILE_PATH = "file:///C:/Users/sshashank/Desktop/db_details.json"
var dbDetailsDF = spark.read
                  .option("multiline", "true")
                  .json(DB_DETAILS_FILE_PATH)
```